# Event handler freezes Front panel

Tags: while-loop, event-handling, labview

I am using simple event handler in the while loop.

I have value change event for the boolean button. There is some code that takes 3-4 seconds to execute.

The problem is I am not able to click anything on my Front panel during this period. Is it possible to allow the user to click on other controls when event handler is working on some case (as I understand the event handler is able to collect all events and process them ASAP)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fully agree with Mikhail N Zakharov's answer, but anyway your problem can be easily solved by just unchecking the checkbox named **Lock panel until the case for this event complates**

Please see screenshot below. 
[image]

PS. Once again it is not the best practise to make event structure to work for 3-4 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to restructure your application to make it more responsive.  LabVIEW best development practices suggest keeping event handler code as fast as possible. One of the ways to handle this would be to send a message into the queue on the change of this Boolean control and process the queue in a separate loop.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is I read data from driver, and it replies after 3 seconds. I just don't want to complicate my architecture.